Is the word "bridge" used to indicate measurement of something in this sentence?
I was reading a scientific article about historical archaeology and then suddenly I came across this part in the article;
"Understanding the development of mass marketing and mass consumption as a way to bridge real socioeconomic distance by relying on cheap but affordable symbols of wealth (decorative coffins or elaborate memorials) also suggests why poor or socially disenfranchised people used similar embellishments."
Specifically, my question is about what is the exact meaning of the verb "to bridge" in this case. I tried to compare it to the meaning explained in the majority of dictionaries on the web which gives the meaning of it being to make lesser the differences between two things, but I can not succeed at making sense out of it by using this definition. On the other hand, I have come to interpret it as "measuring" the distance, but I am still not sure.

It means to reduce the distance or provide a way across the distance. It's the development of mass marketing and mass consumption that's reducing the distance, if that's what's confusing you. If you can't understand that, you'd better tell us why it seems illogical. But you might need to read the rest of the article to understand the processes being discussed.

It's this definition (from Oxford Languages):
make (a difference between two groups) smaller or less significant.
"new initiatives were needed to bridge the great abyss of class".
The passage says that poorer people used 'cheap but affordable symbols of wealth' to 'bridge' the gap between themselves and the wealthier classes.
